# symfony2: should bootstrap.php.cache be in gitignore?

Tags: php, git, symfony

I maintain a working copy of my symfony2 project on several machines, work on them at different times, always pulling the latest dev branch before I start working.

Now, I have the entire vendor directory in gitignore as I believe one should. But When I install my app on a new dev machine, it sometimes receives a more recent version of some vendor libs, since I don't update my vendors regularly on every machine.

This I believe results in a slightly different bootstrap.php.cache on each machine, so should I put that file in gitignore as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be in your `.gitignore`.

I just installed new instance of Symfony 2.3.5 and `/app/bootstrap.php.cache` was included in `.gitignore` by default.

Comment: Thank you. I believe it was upon my adding it to gitignore that it was removed, is this normal behaviour? I did it using the github for Mac visual interface, perhaps it thought it was smart and added a delete command in there as well since I wanted to ignore it, thinking "ok then you don't want this file right?"

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the composer.json file, you should see this `"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap"`

This line is call when you use `composer install` or `composer update` to create the `bootstrap.php.cache` file.

So yes you can add it to your `.gitignore` file.

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for ignoring the bootstrap.php.cache is twofold:

1) it is a cache file, therefore it should not be added to a repo

2) the bootstrap.php.cache is built upon your current vendors. unless you add the /vendor/ folder to the repo (which I do NOT recommend ), you may encounter several misalignment problems between the cache and the vendor libraries

Answer (score 0):

There is a good sample gitignore for symfony here (and it includes bootstrap.php.cache): https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Symfony.gitignore